# LINQ Select Query with Where Condition Which returns single record

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

```
 public ActionResult CreateArea(int? cityid)
        {
            if (cityid == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            var Name = db.Cities.Where(c => c.CityID == cityid)
                     .Select(x => x.CityName);
            ViewBag.message = Name;
            Area city = db.Areas.Find(cityid);
            return View(city);
        }
```

This my ActionMethod in this i want cityname which i m passing to view through viewbag but my LINQ query is wrong it not displaying cityname instead of this query is printing to my view.plz help me to correct my LINQ query.

Comment: First, using debug and check the value of cityid value. And then check data in your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the "execution" of the "expression" like `.ToList()`, `.First()`, `.FirstOrDefault()`, `.Single()` .....

```
var name = db.Cities.Where(c => c.CityID == cityid).Select(x => x.CityName).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var Name = db.Cities.Select(x => x.CityName).Where(c => c.CityID == cityid).FirstOrDefault()

            ViewBag.message = Name;
            Area city = db.Areas.Find(cityid);
            return View(city);
```

try something like this

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the single result from the query and then access the name property:

```
  var Name = db.Cities.Single(c => c.CityID == cityid).CityName;
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help you!

```
  var model =  model.Where(i => i.ParamKey == Key).First();
```